# Environment variables doesn't replace '\n' with new line in javascript and throw error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, environment-variables

I connected to my gmail account with google api using service account.
while doing this, I got credentionals in `.json` file with 'private_key',
looks something like:

`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQCfE0lFOu6odsZd vqCrXHbyFvalkMReFi1bo76tjSpNuJkDlHRKlx0ro+VZ0bqifIbo3yRGST+/Bxyr`

now, I have to deploy my app,
so I added the `private_key` to `.env`,

unfortunatly I get this error:  `Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line`.

when console.log the `proccess.env.private_key`, I get it like this:

`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKYwggSiAgEAAoIBAQCupQiD7fphkibb\nSRJ9x7tJLLWPvL+abF7pUsM30dwSxLtws4O83SFfDnRT9SYebZGz+9EVkv4VtSux\nzOhmLIBc3zUIAQyaD9VZFnZKFf5B0fjD/fp4Oq+AWXtMy`

in one long line... and all the `\n` is still there instead of being replaced by a new line.

Answer (score 4):

```
       let privateKey =  process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/gm, '\n')
```

this regex replace the `\n` to brake line.